# How to create a PHP project in vscode with all dependencies installed?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I swear, I can't find the option like doing with Java, Flutter..
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't quite understand - do you want simply run command "laravel new ProjectName"? In order to create Flutter project you have to install Dart extension, then you'll be able to create new flutter project with ctrl+shift+p

Comment: For Laravel or PHP, cmd + shift + p doesn't work. And running the command "laravel new ProjectName" neither.

Comment: Use the console.

Comment: so install Laravel globally in the first place

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new Laravel project and install all dependencies directly from VSCode.

To create a new Laravel project you should [follow the installation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation#installing-laravel) in the Laravel documentation. E.g. by running the following command from your terminal:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-new-project
```